# how to catch the table data td value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to catch the td value in jquery on mouse click event? I have done these things in pure js but it is lengthy. Can jquery have easy solution? I want to add those catch value in the form text field.

Comment: In JS I would have putted the event on the table element, and when fired I would check what was the actual element that was clicked and act upon...I guess The event object Jquery catches (If it works as the other libraries) has that information in it...Now that there is an answer below, my comment explains exactly what he did there.

Comment: @Itay Yes, the event object that is passed into the click handler has a `target` property, which points to the DOM element that was clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#theTable").click(function(e) {
    var data = $(e.target).closest("td").text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myTable td").click(function(){
            alert($(this).html());
          })
    })
</script>


<table id="myTable" border="1" >
    <tr>
     <td>value 1</td>
     <td>value 2</td>
     <td>value 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). One handler on the container element (table) manages events on all the contained elements (filtered to your preference, e.g. "td"):

```
$('#thetable').delegate('td','click', function(){
  alert('Value is ' + $(this).text() );
});
```